# Ensuring data integrity with 1:n connections in arangodb (delete orphan vertex automatically)

Tags: arangodb

Say I have a `users` document group and another document group `sessionTokens` that store the session the users have. Each user can have multiple tokens but a token can only belong to one user. The association is done through edges.

Now if I use graph functions I can delete a token and the edge between the user and the token gets deleted automatically, and that is great. But what if I want to make sure that if a user is deleted, I want all their session tokens (vertices) to be deleted automatically as well (or else they will be orphan tokens)? Do I have to handle this in application code? Or is there a declarative way to ensure this type of integrity?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/examples-remove-vertex.html),

> ***Deleting vertices with associated edges is currently not handled via AQL*** while the [graph management interface](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/graphs-general-graphs-management.html#remove-a-vertex) and the [REST API for the graph module](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/gharial-vertices.html#remove-a-vertex) offer a vertex deletion functionality.

That said, there are ways to cheat the system, somewhat.  For instance, you can modify several collections at once.  Therefore, you could collect the `_key` values for all the nodes and edges related to the vertex you're removing, then remove each of those in turn.

```js
FOR u IN users
    FOR v,e IN 1 INBOUND u users_sessionTokens
        COLLECT del_users = u._key, del_edges = e._key, del_sessionTokens = v._key
        LET vx = (
            FOR d IN del_sessionTokens
                REMOVE d IN sessionTokens
        )
        LET ex = (
            FOR d IN del_edges
                REMOVE d IN users_sessionTokens
        )
        LET ux = (
            FOR d IN del_users
                REMOVE d IN users
        )
```

It's not necessarily the best implementation, but might work well wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for a way to do this somewhat declaratively within the constraints of a graph (like "cascade" options in SQL) where deleting the user by regular means would take care of the deletion of the previously declared edges and orphaned vertices automatically.

Comment: @RestOfTheBothWorlds - I had the same wish - some sort of "cascade" option.  There are options through the HTTP interface, but most people use a language-specific driver, so those graph functions (gharial) need to be implemented in the driver.

Comment: @RestOfTheBothWorlds - if this answers your question, even if it's not the answer you hoped for, please mark it as such.  It helps others find the information they're after.  Thanks!